# Database not getting updated from Liquibase java API

Tags: java, liquibase

I am using the Liquibase java API to update my database from a databaseChangeLog file. The code is running but the changes are not reflected in the database.
The code is as follows:

```
public class testclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@a_valid_hostname:1521:db11gr2",
                    "[username]", "[password]");
            Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(conn));
            DatabaseChangeLog log = new DatabaseChangeLog("E:\\Delta.xml");
            Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase(log, new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
            liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
            System.out.println("COMPLETED");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Please help me out.

Comment: What output do you get from liquibase? (Annoyingly liquibase will output to stderr whatever you do)

Comment: Also, what is the state of the database before you run this? If the changes are already in place, Liquibase will not do anything.

Comment: You should not post sensitive data here (like hostname, username, pass), especially not all of them at once.

Comment: Thanks @GergelyBacso. I seriously forgot about that part. Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your code more closely, I suspect that you may be using the wrong type of `ResourceAccessor`.

Is the file `"E:\\Delta.xml"` actually on your classpath? If not, change this line

```
Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase(log, new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
```

To

```
Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase(log, new FileSystemResourceAccessor(), database);
```

This tells liquibase to read the changelog file from the filesystem, not the classpath.

Comment: Its not doing any good. The changes are still not reflected in the database.

Comment: When trying from the command line to update the database its happening . But from the code I am unable to update the database.

Comment: Thanks for the help@Woodham. I changed it  and did some additional changes and now its working fine. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @Debdipta: if this answer helps you can upvote and/or accept

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP didn't post how he managed to get this to work, I'm posting a working code here. Mind you, I'm using json ChangeLog and MySQL.

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://*****/test",
                "****", "****");
        Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(conn));
        Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("test.json", new FileSystemResourceAccessor(), database);
        liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
    } catch(Exception e){
        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ｉt works that initializing Liquibase with String as first parameter instead of DatabaseChangeLog. Example as below:

```
    final Connection connection =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?useSSL=false", "***", "***");

    final Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(
            new JdbcConnection(connection)
    );

    final Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("migrations.xml", new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);

    liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
```